# How to uncomment multiple expressions in Lisp code?

Tags: comment

I am using Emacs, Slime, Paredit, and other packages to work on Common Lisp (SBCL).
It is really useful to comment out multiple expressions while debugging.

For instance, suppose I have these placeholder expressions:

```lisp
    (      (  )
     (
       ((   )
         (      (   )
                    ))))
```

I can use the keybinding `C-M-SPC` which run's the command `mark-sexp` on the second line. This character `-!-` will be used to represent the cursor position.

```lisp
    (      (  )
    -!-(
       ((   )
         (      (   )
                    ))))
```

After invoking selecting the region, I can use the command `comment-dwin` to comment the appropriate expressions. Then, Emacs automatically does (using ParEdit):

```lisp
    (      (  )
     -!-;; (
       ;; ((   )
       ;;   (      (   )
       ;;              )))
     )
```

This is great. I just need to learn how to revert this after some editions inside the content of the expressions. Since there were other modifications, I cannot use `undo`. So, how can I remove the `;;` comments in a smart way?

A friend mentioned something like `rectangle-select` but I could not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In emacs, [`comment-dwim`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html) (bound to <kbd>M-;</kbd>) is its own inverse (AKA, [*involution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))):

> Insert or realign comment on current line; if the region is active, comment or uncomment the region instead

I.e., to uncomment the commented region, select and activate the region and hit <kbd>M-;</kbd>.

If you want to avoid activating the region, <kbd>C-u M-x comment-region RET</kbd> will un-comment it.

PS1. [Rectangle](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html)
operations are documented in the manual: <kbd>C-h i m Emacs RET m Rectangles RET</kbd>.

PS2. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65649128/850781 for commenting parts of code.

Comment: FWIW, `comment-region` is (IMO) more flexible/useful than `comment-dwim` for both commenting and uncommenting multiple lines. It deals with nesting blocks of comments as one expects.